# Соединение без доп настроек роутера, Facilitator, NAT punchthrough

Tags: c#, wifi, unity3d, nat

Добрый день. Пишем диплом, ну и попутно надеемся пополнить своё портфолио чем нибудь интересным. 
Планы такие написать мастер сервер, но встаёт вопрос из за недостатка знаний и опыта: 
Допустим игрок выступающий в роли хоста выходит в интернет через Wi-Fi, как другие игроки могут к нему присоединиться без доп настроек wi-fi роутера?

Сёрфинг по тырнету дал пару вещей http://unity3d.com/ru/master-server/  http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/net-MasterServer.html здесь есть такая штука как Facilitator который обеспечит нам NAT punchthrough, но если я правильно понял все данные будут проходить через сервер с фасилитатором т.е. это нагрузка на сервер, возможно ли полностью отбросить это и сделaть соединение напрямую?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямое соединение двух клиентов, находящиеся за (разными) NAT в общем случае невозможно. Это ограничение заложено в самой технологии и его не обойти. Чтобы такие клиенты могли общаться между собой им нужен внешний сервер с "белым" IP-адресом, способный принимать соединения. Тогда клиенты смогут общаться через этот сервер.

Существует технология UPnP (а также NAT-PNP), позволяющая "пробросить" порт с роутера на один из компьютеров внутренней сети. Технология отработанная и присутствует во включенном по умолчанию состоянии практически во всех современных роутерах. Но её применение поможет вам только в части случаев, а именно в тех, где интернет-провайдер выдаёт клиенту "белый" IP-адрес. Но многие выдают "серый" и проблема возникает вновь.

Ещё один вариант обхода ограничений NAT - протокол IPv6, в котором NAT просто не нужен. Но количество провайдеров, предоставляющих IPv6 настолько мало, что об этом не стоит и говорить. Тем более, что большой процент домашних (и даже профессиональных) роутеров не имеет поддержки этого протокола, а у тех, что его поддерживают, он по умолчанию часто выключен.

Резюме. Даже настройки роутера не всегда позволят клиентам извне подключаться к хосту за этим роутером. Единственное *гарантированно рабочее* решение - внешний сервер.